# Bootstrap grid not centering of dynamically sizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a store website with bootstrap. I am creating a grid for my products. My two main problems are that the number of grid cells doesn't change when the screen size gets smaller. I want it to have 1 row when it is really small and 2 otherwise. My other problem is that The grid doesn't center on the screen. Any one know how to do this? Thanks!

The figures are the content in the columns.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ryan's Cookies</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
    <body class="bg-light">
        <!--Shopping cart-->
        <img src="/static/images/cart.png" class="top-right" alt="cart">

        <!--Main Title-->
        <div class="container text-center title-container">
            <h1 class="display-1">Ryan's Cookie Store</h1>
            <h1 class="display-6"><em>Fresh. Delicious. Delivered</em></h1>
        </div>

        <!--Cookie Grid-->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <figure class="figure">
                        <img src="/static/images/chocolate-chip.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <figure class="figure">
                        <img src="/static/images/peanut-butter.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <figure class="figure text-center">
                        <img src="/static/images/nieman-marcus.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50$ <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <figure class="figure text-center">
                        <img src="/static/images/snickerdoodle.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <figure class="figure text-center">
                        <img src="/static/images/tiger.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of details spotted when taking a look might have not been taken into account. I hope this contributes to the first answer and is of value:

[codepen sample](https://codepen.io/LancelotPierreBlaine/pen/dyvZKPr?editors=1000)

Giving the col elements an initial class (col-12) will determine the amount of columns on screens up to *max-width: 575.98px* which is considered ***extra-small***.

The next class with the breakpoint class added (col-sm-6) will determine how many columns there are at *min-width: 576px* which is considered ***small*** and so on and so forth.

Here is a snippet of the breakpoints for bootstrap:

```
    /* Extra small devices col-* (portrait phones, less than 576px) */
    @media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }
    
    /* Small devices col-sm-* (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }
    
    /* Medium devices col-md-* (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }
    
    /* Large devices col-lg-* (desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }
    
    /* Extra large devices col-xl-* (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

And here is what I modified to match what I understand is correct in bootstrap:

PLEASE NOTE: one **row** can hold up to **12 columns** (so I removed the extra rows) and the "**justify-content-center**" class is for ***flex containers*** and doesn't seem necessary when the **text-center** class is on the parent **container**. I also added **container-fluid** and **px-0** to make the columns expand full width. Also, the **no-gutters** class on the **row** lets you specify padding without gutters which can cause overflow issues when misunderstood.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - A Pen by Lancelot Pierre Blaine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <div class="container-fluid px-0 text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <figure class="figure">
                    <img src="/static/images/chocolate-chip.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <figure class="figure">
                    <img src="/static/images/peanut-butter.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <figure class="figure text-center">
                    <img src="/static/images/nieman-marcus.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50$ <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <figure class="figure text-center">
                    <img src="/static/images/snickerdoodle.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <figure class="figure text-center">
                    <img src="/static/images/tiger.jpg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="A generic square placeholder image with rounded corners in a figure.">
                    <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right display-8 mt-1">$7.50 <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm sub-margin">Add To Cart</button></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- partial -->

</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know if this is of any use.

Thanks!